# AWS - Cross-account destination roles are not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

What I am trying to do is define cross delivery between a Firehose stream that is in account A to Elasticsearch that is in account B.

I get "Cross-account destination roles are not allowed" when creating the stream through the c#.

Any one knows why?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you can't configure Firehose in the same account as Amazon Elasticsearch Service? Is there a particular reason for keeping them separate?

Comment: looks like AWS recently added cross-account support for Elasticsearch service: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-kinesis-data-firehose-adds-cross-account-delivery-to-amazon-elasticsearch-service/ :)

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find any mention in the Firehose documentation about allowing an Amazon ES cluster in a different account, but neither did it expressly say it was not possible.

The [CreateDeliveryStream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDeliveryStream.html) API call takes a [DomainARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_ElasticsearchDestinationConfiguration.html#Firehose-Type-ElasticsearchDestinationConfiguration-DomainARN), but it doesn't mention accounts.

The Amazon Kinesis Firehose console certainly doesn't offer the ability to choose a different account. It just displays an empty list and says `You do not have any Elasticsearch domains in this region`.

I don't see how IAM Roles would be involved -- an Elasticsearch cluster has its own policy that controls access to the cluster via username or IP address.

**Bottom line:** It looks like you can't have Firehose stream data to an Amazon ES cluster in a different account.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose now supports delivery to Amazon Elasticsearch Service across accounts. Now your delivery stream and your Elasticsearch clusters can reside in different accounts. This makes it easier for Amazon Elasticsearch Service customers with multiple accounts to ingest streaming data and analyze it in near real time.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-kinesis-data-firehose-adds-cross-account-delivery-to-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

Comment: The AWS news link you pointed is somewhat generic, and you're just telling OP "what you want to do is possible". Maybe you could enrich your answer with some more precise steps?